# PowerQuery expand column containing list

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a table of orders from a data source. Each of those orders has a number of sales reps associated with them. My data source has multiple columns representing those reps. I have created a custom column that appends those names into a list. Because of how I would like to visualize and slice the data, I would like to create a new table from the existing table. The new table would contain the order number column and the list column but would expand the list column to create N number of rows based on how many sales reps were in the list column.

How can I do this using Power Query or DAX in Power BI?

Thank you!

Source Table

| Order # | All Reps | Many other Cols |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | {R1, R2, R3} | stuff |
| 0000012 | {R1, R2} | stuff |

Desired new table

| Order # | Sales Rep |
| --- | --- |
| 1234567 | R1 |
| 1234567 | R2 |
| 1234567 | R3 |
| 0000012 | R1 |
| 0000012 | R2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the All Reps column contains actual lists then in powerquery just use arrow atop that column to expand to new rows

[image]

if you have actual text in there like

[image]

then expand it after converting as follows

```
 Convert = Table.TransformColumns(#"PriorStepNameHere",{{"reps", each Expression.Evaluate(_)}})
```

Comment: Wow, so much simpler than I thought. Thank you for helping me cut out the complexity!

Comment: How can I apply this to multiple columns ?

Comment: Easiest method is to add index, unpivot then repivot